# Types MapColumn, SetColumn, JsonColumn needs owner and record. What actually are these values?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

For example, I have

```
type MapColumn[Owner <: com.websudos.phantom.dsl.CassandraTable[Owner, Record], Record, K, V] = 
    com.websudos.phantom.column.MapColumn[Owner, Record, K, V]
```

`K` and `V` are obvious, but owner and record?  what should I input there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole power of phantom is its ability to map around your data model and give you back type safe results, or so I had in mind when I wrote it. The `Owner` type param is the type of the table written by the user and its needed so you can do stuff like:

```
select.where(_.id eqs id)
```

Looks pretty simple, but the trick is that without the refined type param through which the compiler can "memorize" which columns you have arbitrarily defined inside your table, you would never be able to "know" in the DSL code what columns the user writes.

So the DSL has to know the final type of the table you will create by extending `CassandraTable`.

```
case class MyRecord(id: UUID, name: String)
class MyTable extends CassandraTable[MyTable, MyRecord] {
  object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with PartitionKey[UUID]
  // MyTable is Owner and MyRecord is Record.
  object mapColumn extends MapColumn[MyTable, MyRecord, String, String](this)
}
```

So that's why all the query builders are a function from a `table: Owner` to something else. Even the above is simply shorthand notation for:

```
select.where(table => table.id eqs id)
```

The `Record` type is what makes the Cassandra results type safe. By telling your table what case class it wraps around, phantom is able to map all the results back to this case class using an implicit api approach, so instead of having to deal with things like:

```
res.getString("mystring")
```

Such things are invisible dealt with under the hood, and phantom "knows" which results from a Cassandra row returned belong to which field inside the `case class`. It's immensely less verbose and more efficient, since you don't really want to care how the driver deals with its internal parsing of Netty buffers and CQL message exchanges between a client and the database, you just want your record back.

So the `Record` in combination with the `fromRow` method are needed, and they are passed around not only in those columns, but in every single column. The only difference is that with `StringColumn`, the compiler is able to infer the type of `T` and `R` for you so you don't have to type it.

This is because of:

```
type StringColumn[
  Owner <: CassandraTable[Owner, Record],
  Record
] = com.websudos.phantom.column.PrimitiveColumn[Owner, Record, String]
```

So in reality all columns need this. Collections require an extra parameter(or two in the case of maps), provided by the user, and because of that the compiler isn't able to infer the type like with `StringColumn` or `BooleanColumn`, so you need to type them by hand.

In phantom 1.26.0+, this has been changed, and the extra type parameters are now also invisible, so you will be able to type the following, without having to specify `Owner` and `Record`.

```
object map extends MapColumn[String, String](this)
```

Comment: Thanks for so detailed answer! There's some interesting issue. IntelliJ IDEA highlights (this) with a message "not applicable". However code compiles without any problems. I also found that nested maps are not supported, right?